# Firebase seems to use old data snapshot

Tags: android, firebase

When in the Android app I'm developing I create a new Radiator, the firebase dashboard immediately shows me the new Radiator.
Anyway, when in another Activity i want to retrive all the radiators, it only retrieves the number of radiators of some time ago.
It seems like it is using an old data snapshot version.
I'm working Online and even closing and restarting the app has no impact.
After waiting a few minutes it retrieves the right number of radiators.

```
class RegisteredMaterialValueEventListener implements ValueEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot) {
        listRadiators = new ArrayList<Radiator>();
        if (firstLoad) {
            if (mDataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> i = mDataSnapshot.getChildren();
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> radiatosIterator = i.iterator();
                if (radiatosIterator.hasNext()) {
                    listRadiators.clear();
                }
                while (radiatosIterator.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot c = radiatosIterator.next();
                    listRadiators.add(c.getValue(Radiator.class));
                }
            } 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried onChildAdded? https://www-staging.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: How are you attaching `ValueEventListener`. Because if you're using both `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` and `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`, that combination is known to cause the type of problem you're describing.

Comment: I'm using an addValueEventListener

Comment: No sorry, I was using a addListenerForSingleValueEvent. Changing to addValueEventListener solved the problem. Thank you Frank